# asp.net returning different results in different environments

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

In an asp.net page I am building a checkbox list of items, locally it works as I would expect, however when i put it on the dev server it produces something different entirely.

The code to build the checkbox list items

```
For Each item In _dictOfResult

        Dim value As String = item.key & ": " & item.value

        Dim columns As New ListItem
        columns.Value = "this is a temp value"
        columns.Text = value
        columns.Selected = false
        resultSelectorCbList.Items.Add(columns)
    Next
```

The local page source

```
<input id="resultSelectorCbList_4" type="checkbox" name="resultSelectorCbList$4" value="this is a temp value" /><label for="resultSelectorCbList_4">Applicant: </label>
```

and the dev page source is this

```
<input id="resultSelectorCbList_13" type="checkbox" name="resultSelectorCbList$13" /><label for="resultSelectorCbList_13">Season and Year: </label>
```

Can anyone tell me why the `columns.Value` is not being assigned in dev, and what could cause the difference in behaviours.

Comment: If the same code is in two different places, then I'd rule out code and start looking at things like the data or the .NET packages that are installed (are they the same in both places). I think more information here is needed but I'm not sure what yet.

Comment: Could be dll caching in IIS. Try recycling the IIS pool on which this app is running

Comment: the code is the same in both locations, i too am thinking this is environmental, but its only this bit of code thats not working across all my code on the project

Comment: I agree with Andrei - this is likely a caching issue.

Comment: i have just looked at other known working code and i am having the same issue where the value is not being written on th dev box

Comment: See if you can clear out your IIS cache by recycling the app pool. If that doesn't work (sometimes it doesn't), you may have to manually go in and wipe out the cache files. I forget exactly where they are stored - I think Temporary ASP.NET Files or something. Google will help you there.

Comment: app pool has been recycled and still having the same issue

Comment: @SimonPrice Did you try with: columns.Attributes.Add("Value", "temp value");

Comment: no temp files in the directory and am still getting the issue

Comment: @SivaGopal i will try that now, but why would it work locally and then not remotely

Comment: @SivaGopal worked locally, but not remotely with your solution too

Comment: @SimonPrice Did you try after issuing 'iisreset' from Command prompt and clearing your browser cache? Also what if you add a ListItem to a listbox or anyother list. Is it also showing same behavior?

Comment: i recycled the apppool from the gui on the server, there are also other companies using the server so i have to be careful what i do on there.  I have other checkboxlists and listitems in the site and the behaviour is the same, although this was working